# RiotJS router tag handle navigating away

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I am using tag-based routing with RiotJS `this.on('route', function() {...})` works great, but how to catch **navigating away**? `this.on('unmount', function() {...})` does not get fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to catch it with:

```
this.on('before-unmount', () => {...})
```

Note: There is currently a bug where the DOM gets destroyed in nested tags before `'before-unmount'` ... but it's apparently been fixed in the current 'dev' Riot build.